# Can :hover and :active be Defined Together?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I know that definitions for `:hover` must come before the definition for `:active` in my style sheets. However, is it acceptable to define both styles together (example follows)?

```
p a:hover, p a:active 
{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes sure it is, even saves space!

BTW:

- `a:hover` MUST come after `a:link` and `a:visited`
- `a:active` MUST come after `a:hover`